# Under what circumstances does an AlarmManager PendingIntent get cleared?

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-pendingintent

I am interested to know how far it's possible to rely on a recursive AlarmManager alarm.

The documentation doesn't cover when the alarms get cleared, but from answers on this site here and there, my understanding is that they either only get cleared when the application gets updated/removed/force-stopped/device rebooted, or all the above plus user-removed via task list/inactivity/OOM.

Is there a conscise answer, or is it another one of those things which vary from device to device, ROM to ROM?

Answer (score 0):

There is also Doze mode. In the Doze mode the Alarms are postponed until the doze mode off.

From doze mode [page](https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby); 
 - Standard AlarmManager alarms (including setExact() and setWindow()) are deferred to the next maintenance window.
   - If you need to set alarms that fire while in Doze, use
   setAndAllowWhileIdle() or setExactAndAllowWhileIdle().
   - Alarms set with setAlarmClock() continue to fire normally — the system exits Doze shortly before those alarms fire.

Comment: Yeah, but Doze mode doesn't outright clear the alarms. It just postpones them to the next maintenance window (which iirc is 15 minutes?) and fires them in batches.

Comment: Yes i doesn't. At the beginning, you said how far rely on reliable, so I added into your list.